# Is there an easy way to create a persistent (Header) ajax login modal using Rails and Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone in the Rails community please explain, how I go about creating a login modal experience in Rails using ajax that ALSO lives across every page of the site?

**End Result:**
The experience in the end should mimic the experience found on Kongregate.com. If you notice, they have a persistent login partial that lives in header of their site. If you go to login using that form and are successful, then you are logged in right there on the page. However, if you fail, then you are shown a modal with the login partial, AND the error message/failure reason. The other item of note, if you go to their site and access the "session/new" controller/action then you land on a full page with a login box on it.

I've seen a slew of tutorials which cover AJAX forms in rails but no one seems to talk about the persistent login box in the header which converts to a modal upon failure.

So far I've been able to almost mimic this but I'm lost on what I need in my Sessions Controller.

I have the following:

**SessionsController**

```
def new
end

def create
  @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id

      format.html {
        redirect_to user_url(user), notice: "Logged In!"
      }
      format.js #Not sure what to do here
    else
     format.html { render "new", notice: "Invalid Username/password!" }
     format.js #Not sure what goes here....
    end
  end
end

def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged Out!"
end
```

Comment: are you using a jquery ui modal?

Comment: No I'm not. I'm trying to use Bootstrap's modal.